# Asp.net GridView onclick event when a row is selected through a CommandField button

Tags: asp.net

I've got a GridView which loads information about web domains from a MySQL db, and I want to be able to click the Select commandfield button on the left of the column and be able to save the ID(domainID) of that row to a different db. I plan to link that ID value to data stored in Session["username"] in order to record that user's preferences in a separate db.

I know I can do the part when you insert all this stuff in the db in the code behind but I can't seem to see a way to get the value of the ID when the Select button is clicked.

Below is the code for the gridview.

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gv_Domains" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" CssClass="auto-style16" DataKeyNames="domainID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="368px">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="domainID" HeaderText="domainID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="domainID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="domainName" HeaderText="domainName" SortExpression="domainName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="domainPrice" HeaderText="domainPrice" SortExpression="domainPrice" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

This is the way the gridview looks(sorry if it looks bad but you can't upload pics until you have 10 reputation). I expect to get the number '2' when the Select button on the second row is clicked and then save that number to a separate database on the same row with the value of Session["username"].

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

|/////////// | **domainID** | **domainName** | **domainPrice** |

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

| *Select* | 1        | .com       | 1.99        |

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

| *Select* | 2        | .net       | 3.99        |

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

| *Select* | 3        | .store     | 8.99        |

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

| *Select* | 4        | .co.uk     | 2.49        |

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

| *Select* | 5        | .eu        | 5.99        |

+--------+----------+------------+-------------+

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

Add **OnSelectedIndexChanged** event handler

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Domains" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_Domains_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" CssClass="auto-style16" DataKeyNames="domainID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="368px">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 void gv_Domains_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // Determine the index of the selected row.
          int index = gv_Domains.SelectedIndex;

         //Get domainId
        int domainId = Convert.ToInt32(gv_Domains.DataKeys[index].Value);
  }
```